# How can i capture descriptive text when prompted in Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

Im trying to create a support chatbot using dialogflow. I expect the chat to flow like this

- Customer: Hi my modem does not work --> triggers intent-support
- Bot: Ok sorry to hear that, In just a few words can you describe the fault ?
- Customer: No lights are on , yet its plugged in
- Bot : Ok got it, the fault is : "No lights are on , yet its plugged
  in " I will have one of our team contact you shortly , Bye for now

What is the best approach to capture everything the customer types in after intent-support and not accidentally have it trigger some other intent?

Answer (score 0):

Set a follow up intent after intent-support, since a followup intent cant be triggered by any other intent but its parent, there is no danger of any other intent being triggerd. In the follow-up intent, catch whatever the user says with your custom entities or using the @sys.any entity, wich will match whatever its said